# MSYS2 (64 bit): Can't link header files and libraries when building with cmake

Tags: makefile, build, cmake, linker

I'm still new to building in Windows. I'm building the following project: https://github.com/arkottke/strata.

The page suggests installing dependencies using MSYS2. I've installed MSYS2 and installed everything as instructed, but I get the following (abbreviated) when trying to build using cmake and/or make(?):

```
$> git clone https://github.com/arkottke/strata.git
$> cd strata
$> mkdir build
$> cd build
$> cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
$> make -j2
[  1%] Automatic MOC for target strata
[  1%] Built target strata_autogen
[  2%] Linking CXX executable strata.exe
CMakeFiles/strata.dir/strata_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o:mocs_compilation.cpp:(.text$_ZN12CrustalModelD0Ev[_ZN12CrustalModelD0Ev]+0x8f): undefined reference to `QArrayData::deallocate(QArrayData*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/strata.dir/strata_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o:mocs_compilation.cpp:(.text$_ZN12CrustalModelD0Ev[_ZN12CrustalModelD0Ev]+0x8f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `QArrayData::deallocate(QArrayData*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/strata.dir/strata_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o:mocs_compilation.cpp:(.text$_ZN12CrustalModelD0Ev[_ZN12CrustalModelD0Ev]+0xaa): undefined reference to `QArrayData::deallocate(QArrayData*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/strata.dir/strata_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o:mocs_compilation.cpp:(.text$_ZN12CrustalModelD0Ev[_ZN12CrustalModelD0Ev]+0xaa): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `QArrayData::deallocate(QArrayData*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/strata.dir/strata_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o:mocs_compilation.cpp:(.text$_ZN12CrustalModelD0Ev[_ZN12CrustalModelD0Ev]+0xc5): undefined reference to `QArrayData::deallocate(QArrayData*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [source/CMakeFiles/strata.dir/build.make:2225: source/strata.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:119: source/CMakeFiles/strata.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

According to the GitHub page, this linking error is common, and can be resolved: "If the build is unable to find header files and libraries for linking, paths to these files can be added by modifying the strata.pro text file, or by passing the INCLUDEPATH and LIBS environmental varibles...On Windows, PATH should include the paths to Qwt and GSL DLL files."

If anyone could explain this advice in simple steps it would be once again much appreciated.

Thanks